# Do I have correct understanding of Undefined Behavior for shift operators in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

I want to make sure I understand exactly under what circumstances the `<<` and `>>` operators in C produce Undefined Behavior. This is my current understanding:

Let...:

- `x_t` be the type of `x` after integer promotion
- `N` be the bitwidth of `x` after integer promotion
- `M` be the number of 0s to the left of the most-significant 1 bit in the representation of `x` after integer promotion

`x << y` is UB if any of the following:

- `x < 0` (even if `y == 0`)
- `y < 0`
- `y >= N`
- `x_t` is a signed type and `y >= M`

`x >> y` is UB if any of the following:

- `y < 0`
- `y >= N`

...and is implementation defined if:

- `x < 0`

If I have this understanding correct, it would imply the following:

```
    unsigned short x = 1;
    x << 31;
```

This would be undefined behavior in the case where `int` is 32 bits and `short` is 16 (because `x` would be promoted to `int`, and the left shift by 31 would put the 1 bit into position 31), but it would be defined behavior in the case where `int` and `short` are both 32 bits (because `x` would be promoted to an `unsigned int` and 31 < 32).

Comment: The result of `x << 31` is ignored in your snippet. Is that intended?

Comment: Oh, no it wasn't, though I don't think it matters for the question.

Comment: @ikegami thanks! I had it in my paper notes that I was copying from but missed it somehow. Fixed.

Comment: I do not understand what is `M`. `be the number of 0s to the left of the most-significant 1 bit` There are an infinite number of 0s to the left of any number. I do not understand `most-significant 1 bit in the representation` the representation of which number? Reading the text, I believe by `M` you mean `log2(X_T_MAX)`

Comment: Example: the 8 bit number 00110100 has two zeros to the left of the most-significant 1 bit.

In answer to "which number?": of `x` after integer promotion. So, if `x_t` is unsigned short, it will be promoted to int (assuming an int can represent all values of unsigned short). That's important to specify because you can shift a short more than 16 bits because its promoted to an int (again, assuming e.g. int is 32 bits).

Comment: 8 bits was just an example. The `int` type has some width, and the maximum amount you can shift depends on what that number is. For `unsigned`, you can shift up to `N-1`, and for `signed` you can shift up to `M-1`. So, if `N` is 32 (as is usually the case for `int`), and `x` is 5, then `M` would be 29. That is, you can do `5 << 28` but `5 << 29` is undefined. Make sense?

Comment: @chqrlie: The width of an integer type does not include any padding bits. The C standard defines “precision” to be the number of bits used for the value, excluding any sign bit or padding bits, and “width” to be the number of bits used for the value and sign, if any, excluding any padding bits. The size (in bytes) would include any padding bits.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

I find your definition of `M` a little weak. Specifically, it wasn't clear to me if you were including the sign bit.

But yes, the interpretation is correct.

---

> 3. The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

- `y < 0` ⇒ UB
- `y >= N` ⇒ UB

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum
> value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

This paragraph is poorly worded.

There's no doubt that the behaviour of `E1 << E2` isn't defined when `E1` × 2<sup>`E2`</sup> isn't representable.

- For `x << y`, `x_t` is a signed type and `y >= M` ⇒ UB<sup>[1]</sup>

But what about when "`E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value" is false? `3 << 2` is clearly not undefined behaviour, so that means neither the "then" not the "otherwise" clauses apply when this is false, so that means the spec is silent on the behaviour of `-3 << 2`. It's literally behaviour that's not defined by the spec. So,

- For `x << y`, `x < 0` ⇒ UB

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1`/2<sup>`E2`</sup>. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

- For `x >> y`, `x < 0` ⇒ Implementation defined

---

1. We need to consider not just two's-complement, but ones' complement and sign-magnitude in assessing the validity of this interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have correct understanding of Undefined Behavior for shift operators in C?

Yes, whereas the `M` part is a little vague.

While the `any of the following:` lists some examples, it does not exhaust the whole possible space of behaviors. `INT_MAX << 1` is also UB. The rule is `x * 2**y <= X_T_MAX`, where `X_T_MAX` is the maximum representable value in type `x_t`. That is a 2D plane of allowed numbers.

Comment: In the case of `INT_MAX`, `M` as I defined it is 1. So, that falls under `y >= M`. (okay, I might technically be assuming 2s complement, I'm not sure). I guess the way I'm defining `M` is confusing to people, but basically I'm trying to express that you can't shift a 1 into or through the sign bit. In other words, you can shift up to the number of 0s on the left (again, maybe this is assuming 2s complement, but I'm not concerned about that detail).

Comment: Soo you expressed `x * 2**y <= X_T_MAX` as `y <= M` where `M = log2(X_T_MAX / x)`?

Answer (score 1):

What you have written here is far more cumbersome to comprehend than the actual standard... the TL;DR of C17 6.5.7 can be summarized as:

- UB: Don't left shift variables containing negative values.
- UB: Don't left shift data into the sign bit of a signed operand (the type obtained after promotion).
- UB: Don't shift by a negative or too large shift count.
- Right-shifting variables containing negative values gives implementation-defined behavior in the form of either logical or arithmetic shift. Non-portable.

Done, that's it. No need to make things more complicated.

The golden rule is: never perform bitwise arithmetic on signed types ever. Abide it and you'll avoid a number of well-known bugs.

Comment: How would you write a function pow2mul(int x, int n) that will compute 2ⁿx in all cases where the mathematical values of both -(2ⁿ) and 2ⁿx would be within the range of `int`, if code only needs to run on two's-complement implementations that don't use padding bits (for which C89 defined the behavior of `x<<n` in precisely the desired fashion for the relevant cases)?

Answer (score -1):

Under C89, the behavior of left-shifting an N-bit integer left by 0..N-1 bits was unambiguously defined for all possible signed or unsigned values of the integer, except on platforms where signed and unsigned types had padding bits in different places.  On non-two's-complement platforms, however, behaving in the mandated function may have been less useful than e.g. processing `<<` as a "multiply by power of two" operator, and more expensive than allowing compilers select in arbitrary fashion from among platform-specific interpretations (e.g. sometimes processing `x<<1` as (x+x) and sometimes processing it by actually shifting `x` left by one bit).

Because there was no reason to imagine that implementations for two's-complement platforms would deviate from the C89 behavior, even if allowed to do so, and because people who worked with other platforms would be better placed than the Committee to weigh the pros and cons of handling the construct in precisely-predictable predictable or somewhat-unpredictable fashion, the C99 Committee opted to waive jurisdiction over the behavior of left-shifting negative numbers.  The Committee classified left-shifts of negative numbers as Undefined Behavior because they never imagined that its characterization of actions as "non-portable or erroneous" would be twisted to imply that the Committee judged such actions "non-portable, and therefore erroneous".